# How to set position of spinner upwards in android?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-spinner

is there any way to set the position of spinner upwards instead of dropdown list. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I think this question has been partially answered before here: [Spinner dropUP instead dropDOWN android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910565/spinner-dropup-instead-dropdown-android)

What it states is if your spinner does not have the space below the screen it will inflate the options above. I am not sure if you can manually set this though. But you should not have to as android takes care of it for you.

Comment: No its not exactly what I am asking.

Comment: My Question is how can I set default behaviour of spinner to upwards then downwards

Comment: A way of forcing using this would be to add margin to the top of your spinner to force it down so it will list upwards.

Comment: it is not a proper solution do you have a proper solution?