# How do I create an custom "Drop-Up"-Menu in AndroidStudio [Java]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to crate an dropdown menu which opens form down to top when I click an icon on an circle fixed in the left-bottom corner.

Which Elements should I combine (no code answers necessary)

[Example draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OFfX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) near the bottom of an activity should force it to open upwards, given there isn't enough space to list downwards. A way of forcing using this would be to add a margin to the top of your spinner to force it down so it will list upwards.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910565/spinner-dropup-instead-dropdown-android)